# Table view cell properties remain nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement the concept shown in [this](https://github.com/objcio/issue-1-lighter-view-controllers) example project. My goal is to separate my view controller class and the datasource protocol. Instead of implementing the table view datasource methods in my table view controller class, I try to put it in its own class, and in my view controller, I only call this method to set up my table view:

```
- (void)setupTableView
{
    void (^configureCell)(JVRTodoItemCell *, JVRTodoItem *) = ^(JVRTodoItemCell *cell, JVRTodoItem *todoItem)
    {
        [cell configureForTodoItem:todoItem];
    };

    NSArray *todoItems = currentUser.todoItems;
    self.todoArrayDataSource = [[JVRArrayDataSource alloc] initWithItems:todoItems withCellIdentifier:TodoCellIdentifier withConfigureCellBlock:configureCell];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self.todoArrayDataSource;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[JVRTodoItemCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:TodoCellIdentifier];
}
```

The data source is separated into its own class:

```
@interface JVRArrayDataSource ()

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSArray *items;
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *cellIdentifier;
@property (copy,nonatomic) void (^configureCellBlock)(id item, id cell);

@end

@implementation JVRArrayDataSource

...

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    id item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.configureCellBlock(cell,item);
    return cell;
}
```

The interesting part is that creating the cell based on the identifier (using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) seems to be successful, because the correct cell gets allocated, but its labels remain nil. I try setting up my cell using the following method, but the values remain nil (aTodoItem has valid properties):

```
- (void)configureForTodoItem:(JVRTodoItem *)aTodoItem
{
    self.todoItemTitle.text = aTodoItem.title;
    self.todoItemPriority.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aTodoItem.priority];
}
```

I am trying to figure out what could possibly be missing here, but so far, I haven't managed to fix the issue yet, and I'm starting to lose hope. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
To make it clear, the issue is shown on this picture.

[image: It seems that the cells get created, but its labels don't.]

It seems that the cells get created, but its labels don't.

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `configureForTodoItem:`.  Moreover, I have no idea what you're trying to do with the two lines between creating `cell` and returning `cell`.

Comment: configureForTodoItem: is called from the view controller (in the configureCell block). After creating the cell, I look at the entry in the corresponding row, and call the configure method to set the cell labels for the properties of this entry.

Comment: And where is `setupTableView` called?  I don't understand in the slightest what all this code is trying to do.  What are you overall trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I'll try editing the post. setupTableView is called from my table view controller. The goal is mainly to implement a more generic datasource protocol in a separate class.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why.  The view controller on which the tableview is on, the table view delegate, and the table view data source can all three already be their own classes without any extra work, abstraction, or confusion.  It sounds like you're trying to write a datasource for a datasource.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but this example project (and the article that goes with it) introduces an interesting concept I would like to try and learn, that's the reason.

Comment: Can you link to the article?  I'd like to understand the logic behind this...

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is separate your tableview datasource delegate from the view controller you can create a separate class called `TableViewDataSource`. Within that class you can manage the datasources and their table view cells; configuring the them in your view controller, but letting the `TableViewDataSource` manage them.

**TDSTableViewDataSource.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol TDSTableViewDataSourceDelegate <NSObject>

- (NSString *)fetchCellIdentifierForObject:(id)object;
- (UITableViewCell *)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell usingObject:(id)item;

@end

@interface TDSTableViewDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *items;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<TDSTableViewDataSourceDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**TableViewDataSource.m**

```
#import "TDSTableViewDataSource.h"

@implementation TDSTableViewDataSource

- (NSArray *)items {
    if (!_items) _items = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    return _items;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if ([self.items count]) {
        return [self.items count];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInTableView could not be determined. self.items is nil or empty.");
        return 0;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([self.items count]) {
        return [self.items count];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection could not be determined. self.items contains fewer section requested does not contain any items.");
        return 0;
    }
}

/*
 Single dimension Array of items belonging to a UITableView section

 The method checks if the cell implements the HZConfigureTableViewCellDelegate, which is required.
 The delegate should be the View Controller.
 */
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id obj = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(TDSTableViewDataSourceDelegate)]) {
        NSString *cellIdentifier = [self.delegate fetchCellIdentifierForObject:obj];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (obj)
            cell = [self.delegate configureCell:cell usingObject:obj];
    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

This class and the protocol will essentially allow you to fetch and configure `UITableViewCell`'s and not have to implement the protocols into your View Controller.

Inside your view controller, you create a datasource property using the protocol above.

```
#import "TDSViewController.h"
#import "TDSTableViewDataSource.h"

@interface TDSViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, TDSTableViewDataSourceDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) TDSTableViewDataSource *dataSource; // UITableView data source.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation TDSViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource;
    self.dataSource.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - UITableView methods
-(NSString *)fetchCellIdentifierForObject:(id)object {
    // Check if this is an event or a Reminder class.
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        // Return the cell identifier for this particular cell.

        return @"com.myapp.defaultcell";
    }

    return @"blankcell";
}

- (UITableViewCell *)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell usingObject:(id)item {
    UITableViewCell *configuredCell = cell;

    // Check if this is an event or a reminder.
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        // Configure the cell to present what data we want here...

    }

    return configuredCell;
}

@end
```

This is a complete example project. You can use this to configure any kind of cell you want, without having to add the datasource methods to your view controllers.

The view controller is used by the `ConfigureTableViewCellDelegate` protocol to configure the `UITableViewCell`'s and use them in the Table View. Since the code is segregated now, the `TableViewDataSource` class now handles presenting the data to the table view. The View Controller is simply used to configure the cell's. This allows you to use custom UITableViewCells' on each ViewController if you want, and not have to deal with implementing the data sources each time.

**UPDATED**

Provided a better example, a complete project template.

Comment: Johnathon, thank you for your detailed answer, it's a great example. What bugs me about my question is the fact that my table view cells are not getting created, even though I think I'm doing it the right way..

Comment: One question though: isn't it bad that the TDSTableViewDataSource class holds a strong reference to TDSViewController and vice versa?

Comment: I'm not sure honestly. The reference to the VC could be weak I suppose and just strongly reference it from the VC

Answer (score 1):

In the ViewDidLoad register the nib, it fix the problem :)

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
         [self.leftTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NIB_FILE bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of digging, I've managed to solve the issue (for now), by changing my custom cell's outlets to strong properties, and initializing them in the cell's init method:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.todoItemTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.todoItemPriority = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is very strange, since I thought that creating my views in storyboard, this should be automatically taken care of, and I've never had to do this manually before.

Comment: Yeah there is something else wrong. You shouldn't be setting UITableViewCell views as Strong. It's already strongly referenced by the cell. You are adding these outlets to the header right?

Comment: Yes, they are in the header and they are connected to the corresponding storyboard objects, yet they don't get initialized for some reason.

Comment: Have you set the unique identifiers in the storyboard? Setting the identifiers in storyboard and then calling [cell dequeCellWithIdentifier] within your cellForRowAtIndexPath, it should initialize for you

Comment: I did not set it in storyboard, but from code like this:
`[self.tableView registerClass:[JVRTodoItemCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:TodoCellIdentifier];`

Comment: That is really odd. I'm not sure why you are dealing wig this issue.